# pyQGIS version of the arcgis tool dice

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, python, pyqgis

I'm using QGIS and I have some large features that need to be diced up into features with less vertices.

If I were using arcGIS I could use the [dice tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Dice/001700000037000000/)

If I were only interested in lines I could incorporate [mapplus' solution here](https://github.com/mapplus/qgis-scripts/blob/master/scripts/Split%20Line%20Features%20By%20Vertex%20Count.py)

Is there an equivilent tool that I could script in pyQGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
Here's a python function I wrote, which does the job. The function takes as its inputs: a layer to dice up, the name for the output layer, and the maximum number of vertices for each feature. The output features then also retain their parent attributes and no features in the output layer have a greater number of vertices than the limit passed to the function.

This hasn't been optimised for speed and contains some inefficiencies but it works for polygon layers and for polyline layers. You will need to convert "multi" layers before running it.

It has beeen tested as working on both polygon and line layers.

```
def dice(input_layer,destination_title,max_vertices):
    import numpy  
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    my_WkbType = { 'WKBUnknown': 0, 'WKBPoint':1, 'WKBLineString':2, 'WKBPolygon':3, 'WKBMultiPoint':4, 'WKBMultiLineString':5, 'WKBMultiPolygon':6, 'WKBNoGeometry':7, 'WKBPoint25D':8, 'WKBLineString25D':9, 'WKBPolygon25D':10, 'WKBMultiPoint25D':11, 'WKBMultiLineString25D':12, 'WKBMultiPolygon25D':13 }
    my_rev_WkbType = {v:k for k, v in my_WkbType.items()}
    QGisWKBType=input_layer.dataProvider().geometryType()
    dice_safe_type=False
    if QGisWKBType==3:
        dice_safe_type=True
    if QGisWKBType==2:
        dice_safe_type=True
    if not dice_safe_type:
        raise ValueError("You supplied a "+my_rev_WkbType[QGisWKBType][3:]+" layer and this function only works on Polygon or LineString layers")

    layerQGisType = my_rev_WkbType[QGisWKBType][3:]
    EPSG_code=int(input_layer.dataProvider().crs().authid().split(":")[1])
    destination_layer=QgsVectorLayer(my_rev_WkbType[QGisWKBType][3:]+'?crs=epsg:'+str(EPSG_code)+'&index=yes',destination_title,'memory')
    #QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(destination_layer)
    if not destination_layer.isValid():
        raise("Failed to create memory layer")
    #Add input_layer attribute fields
    input_layer_attrib_names = input_layer.dataProvider().fields()
    oldattributeList = input_layer.dataProvider().fields().toList()
    newattributeList=[]
    for attrib in oldattributeList:
        if destination_layer.fieldNameIndex(attrib.name())==-1:
            newattributeList.append(QgsField(attrib.name(),attrib.type()))
    destination_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(newattributeList)
    destination_layer.updateFields()
    destination_layer_attribute_list=destination_layer.dataProvider().fields().toList()
    #Copy features over to the the new memory layer
    destination_layer.startEditing()
    cfeatures=[]
    xfeatures = input_layer.getFeatures()
    for xfeature in xfeatures:
        gorzirras=[]
        diced=[]
        dice_this_feature=False
        xgeometry = xfeature.geometry()
        slices=1
        if QGisWKBType==2:
            line_as_list = xgeometry.asPolyline()
            if len(line_as_list)>max_vertices:
                gorzirras.append(xgeometry)
            else:
                diced.append(xgeometry)
            while len(gorzirras)>0:
                gorzirra=gorzirras.pop()
                line_as_list = gorzirra.asPolyline()
                dice_left_geometry=QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(line_as_list[:max_vertices])
                diced.append(dice_left_geometry)
                dice_right_geometry=QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(line_as_list[(max_vertices-1):])
                if len(line_as_list)-max_vertices+1>max_vertices:
                    gorzirras.append(dice_right_geometry)
                else:
                    diced.append(dice_right_geometry)

        if QGisWKBType==3:
            rings = xgeometry.asPolygon()
            no_vertices=0
            for ring in rings:
                no_vertices = no_vertices+len(ring)
            if no_vertices>max_vertices:
                gorzirras.append(xgeometry)
            else:
                diced.append(xgeometry)

            while len(gorzirras)>0:
                slices+=1
                gorzirra=gorzirras.pop()
                #Determine longer dimension to split
                bbox_rectangle=gorzirra.boundingBox()
                xmax=bbox_rectangle.xMaximum()
                ymax=bbox_rectangle.yMaximum()
                xmin=bbox_rectangle.xMinimum()
                ymin=bbox_rectangle.yMinimum()
                dice_X=True
                if (ymax-ymin)>(xmax-xmin):
                    dice_X=False
                #Locate median vertex value of long dimension
                ring_list=gorzirra.asPolygon()
                val_list=[]
                for ring in ring_list:
                    for vertex in ring:
                        if dice_X:
                            val_list.append(vertex.x())
                        else:
                            val_list.append(vertex.y())
                median_val=numpy.median(numpy.array(val_list))
                if dice_X:
                    dice_left_geometry=QgsGeometry.fromPolygon( [ [ \
                    QgsPoint(xmin,ymin),\
                    QgsPoint(xmin,ymax), \
                    QgsPoint(median_val,ymax),\
                    QgsPoint(median_val,ymin) ] ] )

                    dice_right_geometry=QgsGeometry.fromPolygon( [ [ \
                    QgsPoint(median_val,ymin),\
                    QgsPoint(median_val,ymax), \
                    QgsPoint(xmax,ymax),\
                    QgsPoint(xmax,ymin) ] ] )
                else:
                    dice_left_geometry=QgsGeometry.fromPolygon( [ [ \
                    QgsPoint(xmin,ymin),\
                    QgsPoint(xmin,median_val), \
                    QgsPoint(xmax,median_val),\
                    QgsPoint(xmax,ymin) ] ] )

                    dice_right_geometry=QgsGeometry.fromPolygon( [ [ \
                    QgsPoint(xmin,median_val),\
                    QgsPoint(xmin,ymax), \
                    QgsPoint(xmax,ymax),\
                    QgsPoint(xmax,median_val) ] ] )

                #Carry out intersections
                left_diced=(gorzirra.intersection(dice_left_geometry)).asGeometryCollection()
                right_diced=(gorzirra.intersection(dice_right_geometry)).asGeometryCollection()

                diced_list=left_diced+right_diced
                for diced_geometry in diced_list:
                    rings = diced_geometry.asPolygon()
                    no_vertices=0
                    for ring in rings:
                        no_vertices = no_vertices+len(ring)
                    if no_vertices>max_vertices:
                        gorzirras.append(diced_geometry)
                    else:
                        #if not diced_geometry.isGeosEmpty():
                        diced.append(diced_geometry)
        #Create destination features
        for ngeometry in diced:
            #print ngeometry.area()
            cfeature = QgsFeature()
            cfeature.setGeometry(ngeometry)
            #Populate feature with attributes
            cfeature_Attributes=[]
            for destination_QGSfield in destination_layer_attribute_list:
                attribute_field=destination_QGSfield.name()
                attr_still_to_append=True
                #Get old attribute value and append
                idx = input_layer.fieldNameIndex(attribute_field)
                if idx>=0:
                    cfeature_Attributes.append(xfeature.attributes()[idx])
                    attr_still_to_append=False
                    #Append a Null into any unfound attributes
                if attr_still_to_append:
                    cfeature_Attributes.append(None)
            cfeature.setAttributes(cfeature_Attributes)
            cfeatures.append(cfeature)
    destination_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures(cfeatures)
    destination_layer.commitChanges()
    destination_layer.updateExtents()
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(destination_layer)
    return destination_layer
```

Simple example showing use of this pyQGIS dice tool:

```
import os
shape_path="/path/to/my/shape/file.shp"
gorzirra_layer = QgsVectorLayer(shape_path, "Gorzirra_layer", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(gorzirra_layer)
diced_title="Diced layer"
vertex_limit=255
diced_layer=dice(gorzirra_layer,diced_title,vertex_limit)
```